# Can i use pointer in scanf to take input in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I am trying to do this in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
scanf("%d",a+i);
```

where `a` is an array of size `10`. And `i` is counter for loop. So is this possible?

Comment: Let's see what you've tried

Comment: Also, if you're specifically looking for a C answer, don't tag C++.

Comment: so long as `a+i` results in a valid writable address for storing an `int`, can you think of a reason this would *not* work ?

Comment: well i am trying to insert an element in an integer array. I have never done it this way. so it would be nice to know how to do it. Anyways, there is no compile time error but there is some logical error as after taking input in an array from the user, I am not able to insert other elements using this. And I am passing the base of an array to another function and using pointer in it to insert the elements.

Comment: Well if you've never done it this way and you're working in C++ why gain a bad habit? Use C++ streams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely: if `a` is an `int*` or an array `int a[10]`, and `i` is between 0 and 9, this expression is valid.

The `a+i` expression is the pointer arithmetic equivalent of `&a[i]`, which is also a valid expression to pass to `scanf`.

Comment: Also works if `a` is `int a[10]` or some such - as long as `i` is in range, of course.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use a+i instead of &a[i],,,, The following code ask you to enter 10 numbers and will save them in an array,,,,and then displays the numbers in it.

check this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a[10], i, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){

    printf("Element no %d = ",i);

    scanf("%d",a+i);}

    printf("Elements in your array are: ");

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)

    printf("%d  ",a[j]);

return 0;
}
```

I hope if this code could help you !!

Answer (score -2):

Try this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int *p, i, j = 0, n;
  printf("enter the value of n ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
    scanf("%d",p+i);}

  printf("Elements in your array are: ");

  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    printf("%d  ",*(p+i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Magish why did you edit like that [in rev 3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42082808/revisions)? Per my reading user asks a question, see their comment above: "I am gettting segmentation fault in this code" (yes this looks like a blatant not-an-answer and I believe should be flagged as such)