# How could I write this without using an integer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char alpha[26] = { '0' };
  char nl;

  while (alpha != '0'){
        scanf("%c", &alpha);
        scanf("%c", &nl);
        printf("the character is %c\n", alpha);
 }



int i, j, size;

  for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    for (j=i;j<size;j++){
      if (alpha[i]<alpha[j]){
        Swap(&alpha[i], &alpha[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%s", alpha);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error "comparison between pointer and integer" in my while loop. I'm wanting to read in each letter of the alphabet from a text file and stop when it reaches a "0" at the end of the list. It's then going to sort alphabetically starting with z,y,x.. etc. How else could I write this so it stops at "0" without using an integer?
Thanks for the help

Comment: `alpha` is an array, but you try to compare it with a character constant.

Comment: You are aware of the difference between character `'0'` and the string termination character `'\0'`, are you?

Comment: The first element of `char alpha[26]` will be initialised to `'0'` and the other 25 to `0`.

Comment: `i<size;` is comparing the loop control to an *uninitialised variable*.

Comment: same OP, almost same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117376/not-sure-how-to-fix-invalid-initializer-error-when-compiling OP still ignoring comments from the last question, downvote

Answer (score 0):

`alpha [26]` is an array of 26 chars, with your `while` loop you always overwrite the first element of the array (`scanf("%c", &alpha);` overwrites the first element of `alpha` in every iteration of the loop ) , the entire code will not work. to access the elements of the array you can either use pointers or indexes, indexes are easier, try a `for` loop

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i<26 ; i++)
   {
     if(alpha[i] != '0')
       {
        scanf("%c", &alpha[i]);
        printf("the character is %c\n", alpha[i]);
       }
   }
```

[C: scanf to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299727/c-scanf-to-array)

for using pointers to access array see [Can i use pointer in scanf to take input in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432494/can-i-use-pointer-in-scanf-to-take-input-in-an-array)

Comment: My guess is it may need to be `scanf(" %c", &alpha[i]);` with a space before `%c`.